# How to change an image in CSS that has no class?

Tags: css

I am on a website that allows you to style your profile with CSS. There is an image I would like to change that is in an  tag, and has no class. So It's not as simple as using the appropriate selector. Is it possible to change an image if its source is a certain link?

Comment: Yes it is.. Show the structure of you HTML

Comment: As I mentioned in the OP, this is not my website.

Comment: Looks like you got your answer.  Nevertheless, you can always inspect element to get the htnl structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [`attribute selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors):

```
[src='http://www.example.com/img.jpg'] {
    /* Styles */
}
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qtbv7xrp/)